# Confluent Cloud - Throughput and Partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

As per the doc https://www.confluent.io/confluent-cloud/pricing/?tab=overview#kafka-clusters , Confluent standard cluster supports throughput Up to 250 MBps ingress and 750 MBps egress (1 GBps total).

Question

1. Is the throughput mentioned is a) aggregated across all topics or
   b) at topic level or c) at partition level?
2. Number of partitions is mentioned as (Hard limit of 4096). If confluent is fully managed, then why do users concern about partitions? Do users need to manually specify number of partitions required? Is it due to throughput defined above are at partition level?

Comment: Since the doc mentions that throughput is at cluster level, its safe to assume that its aggregated across all topics. 

Its managing the infrastructure for you, but you will still need to provide the partitions per topic hence a limit of 4096 partitions per cluster.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because support@confluent.io will be able to better answer this and how quotas are managed on their systems